# Change parent of the class using instrumentation

Tags: java, redis, agent, byte-buddy

I have a class called Client, it is extending Connection class, I want to make a class called KConnection which extends Connection class, and I want that the parent of the Client should not be Connection but it should be KConnection using bytebuddy agent in the premain using AgentBuilder(). something like this

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .type(ElementMatchers.named("Client"))
        .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
          @Override
          public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader) {
            return builder.superclass(KConnection.class);
          }
        })
        .installOn(inst);
```

Can anyone guide me over here..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have reached out to the byte-buddy git hub issues and it was solved. Attaching reference .

https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/1403

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)